# CSS Bottom Border Issues

Tags: css

I was hoping someone could give me some advice on getting rid of the bottom right corner triangles in the `nav` below. Keeping both the bottom border and  white border left after each. thanks!!

[image: Sample image]

CSS Code

```
#top-menu ul{
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  padding:0 0 10 0;
  color:#666666;
  margin-left:64.5%;
  margin-top:0px;
  list-style-type:none;
}

#top-menu ul a {
  float:left;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#ffffff;
  background-color:#5aa1e3;
  padding:0.2em 0.9em;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #B2DEFC;
  border-right: 3px solid white;
}


#top-menu a:hover {
  background-color:#C957BB;   
}
```

here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8RMyU/)

Comment: try to remove border-bottom: 3px solid #B2DEFC;
border-right: 3px solid white;

Comment: I'm trying to keep both borders but remove the points on border- bottom. Sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: could you please create fiddle or attach your html markup?

Comment: Please post your output in fiddle so we can solve the problem easily

Comment: You get the corner because you're setting a bottom and a right border so the triangle is their intersection. The solution is removing `border-right` and replacing it with `margin-right: 3px;`.

Comment: is this what you are going to reach - http://jsfiddle.net/k6JQ3/1/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Remove your `border-right: 3px solid white;` in your `#top-menu ul a` and use a margin instead.

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hJK37/1/)

CSS

```
#top-menu ul a {
  float:left;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#ffffff;
  background-color:#5aa1e3;
  padding:0.2em 0.9em;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #B2DEFC;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bottom right corner is in triangles shape because of `border-right with color`. Now removing the `border:right` there will be no space between items. so you can use `display:inline-block;` to give some distance between Items.  In addition you are using `float:left` many times which really not required in this case.

Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kijotoha/1/edit)**.

```
#top-menu ul{
  width:100%;
  color:#666666;
  list-style-type:none;
}

#top-menu li{ display:inline-block;}

#top-menu ul li a {

  text-decoration:none;
  color:#ffffff;
  background-color:#5aa1e3;
  padding: 1em;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #B2DEFC;
}


#top-menu a:hover {
  background-color:#C957BB;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps you. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8RMyU/1/)

Give the border to `li`

```
#top-menu ul li {
      border-bottom: 3px solid #B2DEFC;
    margin-right: 3px;
    float:left;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may seem unrelated, but bear with me...

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210715/217863

[image]

That's just the way that borders are rendered on a large scale.

Of course if you're just looking for a workaround...

You could cover the bottom border and unwanted corners with a pseudo-element like so:
**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/nASp4/2/)**

```
div:after {
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #808080;
    height: 20px;
    width: 140px;
    left: -20px;
}
```